# Best Design For Saving Users places and address

Tags: database, database-design

Currently, I am adding some ways to store users address just like google maps. Home and Work.

My design was this

```
Places
- id
- label
- latitude
- longitude
- complete_address
- user_id
- created_at
- updated_at
```

Users are allowed to add places with their own labels. My application has a two default label, home and work, if users are going to add a location with label home and a home already exist, I update the current home. same with work. they can add same places with same label as many time as long it does not equal to home and work.

I have problems on my current design.The tables data is not safe for anyone who does not know the business rules. Since you can still insert another home or work places, same with getting the data. I had to set the arrays default value if home and work was not set, so my api will return the default values

```
Get /places

{
  "home" : null,
  "work" : null,
}
```

any best approach to do this? thanks

Comment: What if there are two users at the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allow three lines for the address and limit them to 64 characters based on guidelines from the United States Postal Service. If you're going to have addresses outside the United States you may want to update the fields in this table...

```
address
    id          unsigned int(P)
    line1       varchar(64)
    line2       varchar(64) // Default NULL
    line3       varchar(64) // Default NULL
    city_id     unsigned int(F city.id)
    lat         number(10,3)
    lon         number(11,3)
```

We keep a list of cities in each state...

```
city
    id          unsigned int(P)
    state_id    unsigned int(F state.id)
    name        varchar(50)
```

We have our [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country codes...

```
country
    id          char(2)(P)
    iso3        char(3)(U)
    iso_num     char(3)(U)
    name        varchar(50)
```

This table contains location labels that are "reserved" such as `Home` and `Work`...

```
reserved_label
    id          unsigned int(P)
    name        varchar(20) // Home, Work, etc.
```

We have the United States codes/names from [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:US)...

```
state
    id          unsigned int(P)
    country_id  char(2)(F country.id)
    code        char(2)
    name        varchar(50)
```

We have our users...

```
user
    id          unsigned int(P)
    ...
```

And finally we have our user's addresses...

```
user_address
    user_id     unsigned int(F user.id)
    address_id  unsigned int(F address.id)
    label       varchar(20)
```

As your requirements are right now, your application will have to prevent users from using any `reserved_label` values.

Comment: oh man. i haven't anticipated this. you even fixed the redundancy on my data.